# Postman data array to variable in RAW Post Body

Tags: arrays, post, postman, runner

I'm using a data file for past man with the following JSON with the following data

```
{
    "FirstName": "Jennifer",
    "MiddleName": "Geraldine",
    "LastName": "Gemma",
    "email": "montes.nascetur@vulputatenisisem.net"
    "Phone":[{"Number":"55-(622)813-5953"},{"Number":"233-(935)372-8021"}]}
}
```

I'm attempting to do a post with the following data variables in RAW

```
{
    "FirstName": "{{FirstName}}",
    "MiddleName": "{{MiddleName}}",
    "LastName": "{{LastName}}",
    "email": "{{email}}",
    "Phone": {{Phone}}
}
```

All the data is being populated with the exception of the "Phone". {{Phone}} is not be substituted.

Is there a way of doing this or an alternative way of posting a JSON request?

OR

Is there an alternative way of posting this information in JSON using Postman from a data file?

Comment: Thanks for `"{{variable}}"` in Postman.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Pre-req. tab of your request to enter JavaScript code. There you can iterate through the array `data.Phone` and stringify each entry in the array, `JSON.stringify`, and construct a concatenated string (say phone_numbers). Then you can set this value to a variable:

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("phone_nos", phone_numbers).
```

This "phone_nos" variable can then be referenced in the RAW request body.

```
"Phone" : {{phone_nos}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an array into a string as shown below in the data file.

```
{
   "FirstName": "Jennifer",
   "MiddleName": "Geraldine",
   "LastName": "Gemma",
   "email": "montes.nascetur@vulputatenisisem.net",
   "Phone": "[{\"Number\":\"55-(622)813-5953\"},{\"Number\":\"233-(935)372-8021\"}]}"
}
```